# Xamarin Forms Android - Display .ico Image - Error: could not find any valid embedded ico codecs

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to display an icon related to a website by using its favicon.ico file.

On some devices this works fine however on others I get the following error in the console and the image appears blank:

> Error: could not find any valid embedded ico codecs.

Is there a way to include additional codecs or can anyone suggest a way to convert this is a PNG in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: I am not sure if `.ico's` are even supported

Comment: If you are not developing an app that focuses on converting image formats, it is recommended that the server handle image conversion. The client does not recommend limiting the display to a format. The best format currently used in Xamarin is the `PNG` or `JPG` format.

Answer (score 1):

Found a usefull image API called SkiaSharp to convert between .ico and .png in Xamarin Forms:

**Docs:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp?view=skiasharp-1.68.0

**Nuget:**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp

**Example:**

```
var iconUri = new Uri(this.URI + "/favicon.ico");
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(iconUri);                           

    using (var bmp = SkiaSharp.SKBitmap.Decode(imageBytes))
    {
        using (var img = SkiaSharp.SKImage.FromBitmap(bmp))
        {                                    
            using (var imgData = img.Encode())
            {
                using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    imgData.SaveTo(ms);
                    imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }    

    this.Icon = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes));
}
```

Note: I intend to make improvements later to get the favicon by parsing the HTML to find the `<link rel="shortcut icon"` tag